# Installing older version of Maven 2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: maven-2, ubuntu, apt-get

Is there an easy way to use apt-get to install an older version of Maven 2 on Ubuntu Maverick? 
I'd like to use 2.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from launchpad: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/15563514/maven2_2.0.9-2_all.deb

Double-click on it and GDebi should do the rest.

This package is no longer maintained on LTS and newer versions. Be careful, I haven't tried it because I have a newer version.

Anyway, why would you use an older one?

More info here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jaunty/+package/maven2